# Summation of $\sum\limits_{j=2}^n j = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} -1$

Tags: summation

I've know that 
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n k$ is $ \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. 
Then why 
$\sum\limits_{j=2}^n j = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} -1$ ? I understand that i=1 $\neq$ j=2 is the key, but I can't get further.

from : Introduction to Algorithms (3rd edition) p. 27

Comment: Note $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n j = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $ and $1+\sum\limits_{j=2}^n j=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n j $.

Comment: Of course. It was so obvious. I can't believe I couldn't see it. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${n(n+1)\over 2}=\sum_{k=1}^n k = 1 + \sum_{k=2}^n k.$$

Comment: Vey clear thank you. It was so obvious!!!! Thanks for taking time to pointing it out! I got it !